# How to replace "errorr"-records with 0 in SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL Access query in which I need to have calculated FY16 to FY17 Growth. For growths with error (divided by 0) I want to see 0 instead of error. I am trying to use Iif function: `Iif(FY16 = 0, 0, (FY17-FY16)/FY16)` but it still gives me errors instead of "0"-s. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
  CountriesComm.Code,
  CountriesComm.ProductCode,
  COTsAbbriviation.Abbriviation,
  CountriesComm.FY16Q1,
  CountriesComm.FY16Q2,
  CountriesComm.FY16Q3,
  CountriesComm.FY16Q4,
  CountriesComm.FY17Q1,
  CountriesComm.FY17Q2,
  CountriesComm.FY17Q3,
  CountriesComm.FY17Q4,
  (CountriesComm.FY16Q1+CountriesComm.FY16Q2+CountriesComm.FY16Q3+CountriesComm.FY16Q4) as [FY16 Total],
  (CountriesComm.FY17Q1+CountriesComm.FY17Q2+CountriesComm.FY17Q3+CountriesComm.FY17Q4) as [FY17 Total],
  Iif((CountriesComm.FY16Q1+CountriesComm.FY16Q2+CountriesComm.FY16Q3+CountriesComm.FY16Q4)=0,0,
  ((CountriesComm.FY17Q1+CountriesComm.FY17Q2+CountriesComm.FY17Q3+CountriesComm.FY17Q4)-
  (CountriesComm.FY16Q1+CountriesComm.FY16Q2+CountriesComm.FY16Q3+CountriesComm.FY16Q4))/
  (CountriesComm.FY16Q1+CountriesComm.FY16Q2+CountriesComm.FY16Q3+CountriesComm.FY16Q4)) as [FY17 Growth],
  (CountriesComm.FY17Q1/[FY17 Total]) as [FY17Q1 Phase],
  (CountriesComm.FY17Q2/[FY17 Total]) as [FY17Q2 Phase],
  (CountriesComm.FY17Q3/[FY17 Total]) as [FY17Q3 Phase],
  (CountriesComm.FY17Q4/[FY17 Total]) as [FY17Q4 Phase],
  ([FY17Q1 Phase] + [FY17Q2 Phase] + [FY17Q3 Phase] + [FY17Q4 Phase])/4 as Check
FROM
  COTsAbbriviation INNER JOIN CountriesComm ON COTsAbbriviation.COT = CountriesComm.ProductCode
ORDER BY
  CountriesComm.Code,
  CountriesComm.ProductCode;
```

Comment: Where is the error ? Maybe it is from  FY17Total = 0 from (CountriesComm.FY17Q1/[FY17 Total]) as [FY17Q1 Phase],

Comment: @Mono, I was having errors for [FY17 Growth]. To solve my issue I needed to erase brackets where I am decreasing FY17 by FY16

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the errors are due to `NULL` values in the FY quarter columns. If at least one is present, entire equation becomes `NULL` and so using it division will result in error. Consider using `Nz()` to render null to zero:

```
IIF((Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q1) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q2)
     + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q3) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q4)) = 0, 0,      
    ((Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q1) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q2) 
     + Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q3) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q4)) -
     (Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q1) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q2) 
     + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q3) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q4))) /
     (Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q1) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q2) 
     + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q3) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q4))) as [FY17 Growth]
```

As you can see, this can be a bit tedious and hard to read. So, one alternative is to use the unique aspect of Access SQL of using calculated columns in other expressions of the same query (which you already employ with `[FY17 Total]`:

```
(Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q1) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q2)
 + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q3) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY16Q4)) As [FY16Sum],

(Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q1) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q2) 
 + Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q3) + Nz(CountriesComm.FY17Q4)) As [FY17Sum],

IIF([FY16Sum] = 0, 0, (([FY17Sum] - [FY16Sum])/[FY16Sum])) AS [FY17 Growth]
```